# Confusion regarding Ito Differentiation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $x_t \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the stochastic process

$$
\mathrm{d}x_t = (Ax_t + Bu_t) \textrm{d} t + D\textrm{d}w_t, \quad t\in [0,T],
$$
where $w_t$ is the standard Brownian motion.
Suppose I also have a function $f(x_t) := \frac{1}{2}x_tP_tx_t$, where $P_t = P_t^\intercal > 0$ is a positive-definite, symmetric matrix that satisfies the Riccati equation

$$
-\frac{\textrm{d}P_t}{\textrm{d}t} = P_t A + A^\intercal P_t - P_t(BR^{-1}B^\intercal-\mu DD^\intercal)P_t + Q, \quad P_{T} = M.
$$

I am currently reading a paper that states:

\begin{align*}
f_T - f_0 &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\left(x_t^\intercal\left[P_tBR^{-1}B^\intercal P_t -Q\right] x_t + 2u_t^\intercal B^\intercal P_t x_t\right)\textrm{d} t + \int_{0}^{T} x_t^\intercal P_t D \textrm{d} w_t \\
&- \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T} \left(\mu x_t^\intercal P_t D D^\intercal P_T x_t + \textrm{tr}\left[P_t DD^\intercal\right]\right) \textrm{d} t,
\end{align*}

and I would like to verify this myself but am having difficulties.
The first step is to recognize that the endpoint difference $f_T - f_0$ can be computed from the Ito differential

$$
f_T - f_0 = \int_{0}^{T} \textrm df_t.
$$

Next, Ito's lemma states

$$
\textrm{d} f(x_t) = \left[(\nabla_x f)^\intercal (Ax_t + Bu_t) + \frac{1}{2}\textrm{tr}(D^\intercal H_xf D)\right]\textrm{d}t + (\nabla_x f)^\intercal D \textrm{d} w_t,
$$

where $\nabla_x f$ denotes the gradient and $H_x f$ denotes the Hessian.
Computing the gradient gives $\nabla_x f = P_t x_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the Hessian $H_x f = P_t \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
As a result,

$$
\textrm{d} f_t = \left[x_t^\intercal P_t(Ax_t + Bu_t) + \frac{1}{2}\textrm{tr}(D^\intercal P_t D)\right] \textrm{d} t + x_t^\intercal P_t D \textrm{d} w_t.
$$

However, in the paper, it is clear that the *differential* $\textrm{d} P_t$ appears in the integrals, but I am not seeing where this differential comes from in Ito's lemma.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $f$ is also a function of $t$ through $P_{t}$, you should use Itô's formula for $f\left(t,x_{t}\right)$, where the drift term is
$$\begin{align*}
&\quad\ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\left(\nabla_{x}f\right)^{\top}\left(Ax_{t}+Bu_{t}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left(D^{\top}H_{x}fD\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}x_{t}^{\top}\left[-P_{t}A-A^{\top}P_{t}+P_{t}\left(BR^{-1}B^{\top}-\mu DD^{\top}\right)P_{t}-Q\right]x_{t}\\
&\ \ +x_{t}^{\top}P_{t}\left(Ax_{t}+Bu_{t}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left(D^{\top}P_{t}D\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[x_{t}^{\top}\left(P_{t}BR^{-1}B^{\top}P_{t}-Q\right)x_{t}+2x^{\top}P_{t}Bu_{t}+\mathrm{tr}\left(D^{\top}P_{t}D\right)-\mu x_{t}^{\top}P_{t}DD^{\top}P_{t}x_{t}\right].
\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks! Good catch/.

Comment: What happened to the $A^\intercal P + PA$?

Comment: @JoshPilipovsky They added up and canceled with $+x_{t}^{\top}P_{t}Ax_{t}$. Note $x_{t}^{\top}P_{t}Ax_{t}$ is a scalar, hence equals to its transpose $x_{t}^{\top}A^{\top}P_{t}x_{t}$.